# base_url() not echoing value when data is received from database CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a website that if fully dynamic from page building,menus etc now previously before making it dynamic i made static pages for the client and after that he told me make everything dynamic!

i am using summernote editor for dynamic editing now summernote has an option of custom html in which we can write our code so what do i do simply is i copy the code from static pages one by one and add the html to summer note custom html editor side! now everything is working fine as it should but what happens it that on the front end base_url() variable is not echoing the path as it normally should,now the data of the page is received from database the variable syntax is fine i have also autoloaded **url** in my config file but still it is not working here is a demo of the code.

**html**

```
    <?php include "includes/header-others.php" ?>
        <div id="parent_margin">
            <div class="container generic generic_diagnostic">

        <?php
        print_r($text[0]->page_data); //this line is printing the result from database
?>

        </div>
    </div>
<?php include "includes/footer-others.php" ?>
```

**An example how data is being stored in db**

```
<img onclick="blur_image(this.id)" src="<?=base_url()?>images/ourteam_1.png" class="img-responsive"/>
```

i dont know what is the issue! the same html code works fine when using in static pages and on dyamic pages where datab comes from db its does not echo the value of base_url()..

Comment: I've just realised what you're trying to do. This is just a bad idea but you can always echo str_replace('<?=base_url()?>', base_url(), $dbstring);

Comment: without the php parenthesis it wont work it will show as regular text

Comment: Make sure your `<?=` short tag is active.  or replace using `<?php echo`

Comment: @Callombert `echo str_replace('<?=base_url()?>', base_url(), $dbstring)`? I'm pretty sure that it will end with parse error.

Comment: Tip On codeigniter you can load views on view like `<?php $this->load->view('footer-other');?>` this way you don't have to use include and https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views